# Enforce comments in function implementation

Tags: c++, c, comments

I am looking for a way to enforce adding comments for code blocks inside functions. for example I want each for loop, if condition etc. to have one or two lines of comments describing what the code actually does.

I know Doxygen and I know it is not capable of doing this task. is there any other tool that can be used to give some information/metrics about the quality and amount of comments in function implementation?

Comment: You should strive for code clarity, rather than enforcing silly rules about how many lines of comments there should be but that's just my opinion.

Comment: your point is valid but on my project I have a requirement to have comments on implementation.

Comment: How do you imagine a tool would measure the quality of the comments without understating the code itself, the comment and your expectations? Such a tool would probably be capable of writing the code in the first place.

Comment: the command-line tool awk is the normal starting point for this kind of thing. Have a look here: https://code.google.com/p/line-counting/source/browse/trunk/lc.awk

Comment: With all due respect to whoever invented it, but this is one of the silliest coding requirements I have ever heard of. Try to question it harder.

Answer (score 1):

What could be interesting is to search for methods with a high cyclomatic complexity(using many if,for,while,..) and not well commented, for that you can use [CppDepend](http://www.cppdepend.com) and execute a CQLinq request like this one:

[image]